# Scripting a conditional formula in field calculator QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I'm trying to write down a script in the field calculator but I'm getting to nowhere.

In one field I have runoff data, and in two other ones I have the first quartile of the runoff data (Q1) and the third quartile (Q3) of the runoff data. Basically what I'm trying to achieve is to replicate my excel formula inside the field calculator:

```
=IF(N3<=Z3;"A";IF(N3>=AA3;"B";IF(AND(N3>Z3;N3<AA3);"C";0)))
```

with:

N3= runoff data

Z3= Q1

AA3= Q3

Inside the attribute table, I have the three fields (runoff, Q1 and Q3) labelled in the same way.
As I'm fairly new to the scripting method, I don't know the syntax I need to respect in my field calculator formula.

Comment: Test this : `if("runoff" <= "Q1", 'A', if("runoff" >= 'Q3', 'B', if("runoff" > "Q1" AND "runoff" < "Q3", 'C', 0)))`